java 1.8 on macos: Could not find tools.jar
I installed java 8 jdk on MacOs
 /usr/libexec/java_home -V | grep jdk

Matching Java Virtual Machines (1):
    1.8.411.09 (arm64) "Oracle Corporation" - "Java" /Library/Internet Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin/Contents/Home

It is installed !
When building a flutter (old !) app in android studio, I got this
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':firebase_messaging:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> Could not find tools.jar. Please check that /Library/Internet Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin/Contents/Home contains a valid JDK installation.

What should I do ?
My ls -la of the folder is
% ls -la
total 56
drwxr-xr-x  13 root  wheel   416 13 Mar 08:24 .
drwxr-xr-x  10 root  wheel   320 27 Mag 10:13 ..
-rw-r--r--   1 root  wheel  3245 13 Mar 08:23 COPYRIGHT
-rw-r--r--   1 root  wheel    44 13 Mar 08:23 LICENSE
-rw-r--r--   1 root  wheel    46 13 Mar 08:23 README
-rw-r--r--   1 root  wheel   190 13 Mar 08:23 THIRDPARTYLICENSEREADME-JAVAFX.txt
-rw-r--r--   1 root  wheel   190 13 Mar 08:23 THIRDPARTYLICENSEREADME.txt
-rw-r--r--   1 root  wheel   955 13 Mar 08:23 Welcome.html
drwxr-xr-x  17 root  wheel   544 27 Mag 10:13 bin
drwxr-xr-x   4 root  wheel   128 13 Mar 08:24 legal
drwxr-xr-x  99 root  wheel  3168 13 Mar 08:46 lib
drwxr-xr-x   5 root  wheel   160 13 Mar 08:24 man
-rw-r--r--   1 root  wheel   168 13 Mar 08:23 release

and this is listing of bin subfolder
% ls -la
total 3688
drwxr-xr-x  17 root  wheel     544 27 Mag 10:13 .
drwxr-xr-x  13 root  wheel     416 13 Mar 08:24 ..
lrwxr-xr-x   1 root  wheel       8 27 Mag 10:13 ControlPanel -> jcontrol
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root  wheel  174672 13 Mar 08:41 _javaws
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root  wheel  154080 13 Mar 08:41 java
lrwxr-xr-x   1 root  wheel      47 27 Mag 10:13 javaws -> /Library/Application Support/Oracle/Java/javaws
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root  wheel    3972 13 Mar 08:24 jcontrol
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root  wheel  154032 13 Mar 08:42 jjs
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root  wheel  154048 13 Mar 08:42 keytool
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root  wheel  154048 13 Mar 08:42 orbd
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root  wheel  154048 13 Mar 08:42 pack200
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root  wheel  154048 13 Mar 08:42 policytool
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root  wheel  154048 13 Mar 08:41 rmid
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root  wheel  154048 13 Mar 08:41 rmiregistry
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root  wheel  154048 13 Mar 08:41 servertool
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root  wheel  154048 13 Mar 08:42 tnameserv
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root  wheel  150208 13 Mar 08:41 unpack200


JDK should be in the /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines path. What you have is the Java plugin.

That's not a JDK. That's a JRE. Up through version 8, Oracle (and earlier Sun) Java is (was) distributed in two forms: a Java Runtime Environment (JRE) for runtime-only and a Java Development Kit (JDK) for development plus runtime. tools.jar are development tools and are provided only in the JDK not in the JRE. (In 'modular' Java versions 9 up, Oracle distributes only the JDK, but some other OpenJDK builders continue to provide JRE and JDK packages.)

The tools.jar file on the 1.8.0 JDK is located in jdk1.8.0/lib/tools.jar. If you can't find it, then you don't have the JDK installed correctly.
